# How to find time difference in minutes from database last inserted record time and current time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

---

How to finding minutes using last inserted record datetime and current datetime,that time i want to show in repeater control.

Example Like:

```
 1. Amit     20/12/2013  09:38:45
 2. Vimal    01/06/2014 12:00:50
 3. Mitul     08/07/2014  04:04:04
```

In that table last inserted record is **'3'** ,then select that record datetime .

datetime using into finding minutes like that :

```
datetime - current datetime=minutes
```

that minutes show into repeater control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(n, A.datetime , GETDATE()) AS minutes
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY datetime  DESC) AS A
```

Comment: @Aks: refer this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`DATEDIFF`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx) function with Datepart `Minute(MINUTE,mi,n)`

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [datetime] , GETDATE()) as Minute_Diff
FROM   Table 
ORDER BY datetime  DESC
```